# Use thunar and not Caja to open CDs and DVDs

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, media, caja

Using Ubuntu Mate 18.04

When I insert a CD or DVD, I want thunar to open it and not caja.

When I go to media handling under Caja preferences and pick use Thunar for CD and DVD, it stays at Do Nothing?

Can that be changed?

Comment: Thunar is the default desktop handler for Xfce, therefore it doesn't have the permissions. There can be a bunch of issues running two file managers. How did you install Thunar? Did you change how Caja handles the desktop? You can to set Thunar to open files and media but leave Caja to handle desktop operations. These can be found in settings and preferences. I've done this in Mate but used Nemo instead as it's far better than Thunar imho.

Comment: I have the Mate desktop, not Xfce. I installed Thunar with package manager.